# PHP Session variable timeout

Tags: php

My application uses some session variables that are timing out even though I thought they would not because I've got the following setting in php.ini:

session.cookie_lifetime = 0

The other session settings in php.ini are pretty much set as their defaults. How do I make sure the session variables stay around until the browser window closes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you set the session timeout with **session.gc_maxlifetime** which defaults to 1440 seconds - 24 minutes

Comment: gc = garbage collect. After 1440 seconds a session which does gc will delete it.

Comment: yup, so after this time the session might have disappeared even if the cookie is still there

Answer (score 3):

Note that since PHP 4.2.3 the life time is calculated on the base of the modification date and not the access date (see [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)). So you have to update the session data on every request to “reset the timer”.

Comment: Is there any hazard to setting a longer value, such as 10800 (3 hours)? I don't THINK disk space is an issue.

Comment: I'm considering going as high as 10 hours for gc_maxlifetime. Is the only consideration how much disk space is taken up by the files until they're deleted? Any other complications?