# preventing access to php file function

Tags: php

I made a php script that acts as a to-do list. On the admin side (just admin.php), there is a display table, and this table fetches each record from the to-do list table in mysql, then places a remove button next to each record.

[image: Click Here For Image]

Every remove button has an anchor tag with an ID based on the specific associated row from mysql. So when someone clicks the remove button, the url goes to `/remove.php?id=ROWID`

The issue is that someone could enter that url from any page with the proper rowid, they could delete the data. On the remove.php, I am using the `$_GET` method, to get that ROWID. I could make a form and have that POST, which I have for other functions on the site. But even for those, if someone types in add.php, they could still access the add functions within the php script.

I tried starting a session using session_start(); in the admin.php page (which will eventually be locked to only authenticated users who have admin rights), but if someone knows the link, they are still able to go to `/remove.php?id=ROWID` even without being in the session, or stating a session from admin.php

Am I missing something? Is there a way to prevent access to remove.php expect for users who are authenticated or within the session?

Comment: `HTTP GET` should **only** be used for reading. Even so, you'll still need to implement a login and access control layer - or at least a simple `HTTP Basic Auth`

Comment: Did you try to use `if`?

Comment: `remove.php` needs to check the session variable to ensure that they're logged in.

Comment: @barmar so something like
accepted
if (isset($_SESSION['errors']))
{
    //Do stuff
}

Comment: More like `if (!isset($_SESSION['admin'])') { die("You're not logged in as admin"); }`

Comment: @barmar I will try this in just a sec, but the logic behind this is that they would need to access admin.php first, and if so they are then apart of the session and can access the remove.php?

Comment: Yes, that's the point.

Comment: @Barmar Worked like a charm. Is there a way to put a timeout or specify the length of time that the session is good for ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450997/php-session-variable-timeout

Comment: @Barmar Do you know how  I could bind an error message if I am referring the user back to the page they came from? For instance, they go to access remove.php and then they are returned to the page they came from using: header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");    but how would I bind an error message to that ?

Comment: You could add a URL parameter like `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . '?error=message'`, and then the page could check for `$_GET['error']` and display the message somewhere.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks again for your help! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the above post,

I used:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ID'])){
    code goes here for if they are authenticated
}else{
    die("You're not logged in as admin"); 
}
```

This will start a session on page1.php and on page2.php will check if a session was started from page1. If not, the error (die) message will be displayed.

If you want to expire the user’s session based on some length of time, use this example:
http://thisinterestsme.com/expire-php-sessions/

Comment: I think you should consider  `if (!isset($_SESSION['ID'])) die("You're not logged in as admin"); ` as it may be easier to read if you have a lot of code

Comment: @sr9yar I just incorporated a session timeout, so now my code includes the above with an additional if statement within the "code goes here", and then the if (!isset) at the very end of the code to evaluate if the variable is not set on page1.php.